# How to not replace letters in R

Tags: command-line, r

While using R, suddenly (I don't really know what I did)
it started erasing my commands and overwriting when I am trying to change a command or a loop. When I use backspace the text is getting closer, I lost the ability to use space and actually create some! It simply overwrites!

Any help to avoid typing everything again?

Comment: Have you touched that perky Insert key on your keyboard?

Comment: Maybe  I did! now everything is fine, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

If you're using a laptop, you may have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> button to make some extra key work like <kbd>Insert</kbd>. For example my Asus laptop doesn't have separate <kbd>Insert</kbd>, but pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> does the same.

Answer (score 0):

My HP laptop has 'ins' written over the print screen button. Pressing function + print screen stopped the overwriting in R.